# Where I can deploy my dynamic web projects online for free?

Tags: dynamic, github, projects

I am trying to test my web app which includes jsp on some site. Is their any site which can do that like github or eatj?

Answer (score 1):

[Heroku](http://heroku.com/) will let you host web apps for free. The free tier has some limitations, but for testing it should work fine.